# SSRS - Passing one date parameter and using it as between

Tags: sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

Hi I am workikg with an SSRS report wherein i am passing a date from one report to anothere report with this sample format 7/6/2013, my problem is iam using this to the second report like this:

```
select recordnumber, employeename, empolyeeID, team, step, QA, convert(char(10), hireDate, 120) as hireDate, EmpStatus,Comments, convert(char(10), AssignDate, 120) as AssignDate
from tblQMRoster tr
inner join tblQATeamMaster tm
On tr.QAMemberID = tm.QAMemberID
inner join tblStepMaster sm
ON sm.stepDesc = tr.step
where sm.stepid = @StepID and tr.QAMemberID = @QAMemberID
and AssignDate like between  @Assigneddate and @AssignedDate
```

I had already tried AssignedDate like @AssignDate + '%' since i am only getting one day worth of data when the link in my report is clicked but the problem with this is i am getting all the reports not covered by my parameter.

Comment: What are the datatypes of the `AssignDate` column and the `@AssignedDate` parameters? `date`, `datetime` or `varchar` / `string`?

Comment: I convert it to nvarchar since if its dates usine like is not possible..

Comment: why dont you use two parameters for between

Comment: because i am only passin gone date from other report

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can't you just use:

```
AND     AssignDate >= @Assigneddate 
AND     AssignDate < DATEADD(DAY, 1, @AssignedDate)
```

Two articles that are well worth a read on the subject:

**[What do BETWEEN and the devil have in common?](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common)**

**[Bad habits to kick : mis-handling date / range queries](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/16/bad-habits-to-kick-mis-handling-date-range-queries)**