# How to configure parameter dates in SSRS

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, reporting-services

I have an SSRS report where in i have two parameters @startdate and @endDAte, my problem is for example i want to pull data dated 10/21/2013, i should input 10/21/2013 as start date and 10/22/2013 as end date because if i input 10/21 for both start and end date it will not return 10/21. I believe its interpreting the input parameter start date and enddate 10/21/2013 00:00:00, i want to pass an end date like 10/21/2013 59:59.999 so to pull all 10/21/2013 data. I already used functions to convert enddate to this format and ive tried to set defaultvalues to mm/dd/yyy + " 23:59:59" but its not working. Please help. Thanks

Comment: What's wrong with the approach suggested in your previous question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19492671/ssrs-passing-one-date-parameter-and-using-it-as-between, i.e. just adding one day to the end date and using `<` as the comparison operator?

Comment: This is a different report, first one is im just passing one parameter and intended to get just one day, while this one is for different ranges of dates, not wrong with your answer on the first one. :)

Comment: Not my answer - just one I happened to remember - thanks for the update!

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to time components to default values for dates.

e.g. To set the default to the end of today, use the default expression as:

```
=CDate(Format(Today(), "yyyy-MM-dd" & " 23:59:59"))
```

[image]

Note the Format string is using `MM` (i.e. months) and not `mm` (i.e. minutes).

However, I think you'd be better served by the approach suggested in your previous question, i.e. something like this in the T-SQL behind the report:

```
AND MyDate < DATEADD(DAY, 1, @EndDate)
```

This seems more clean and intuitive than trying to add certain time components to a date the user selects - what if they override the default and remove the time part?

Comment: This answer was helpful because report I am working on needed to have defaults for date&time parameters.